# What is this icon supposed to be and what does it mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I can't find an explanation for this, I tried googling VS symbols, icons, locals window, a few combinations. I get lots of results about all manner of non-related subjects - but none that explain what I'm looking for:

The following icons relate to string fields (at least in my current run) in my Visual Studio 2015 Community Locals Window, which I have running a C# program.

The top one has a little rosette or something on it - what is this actually an image of (not a rosette I assume) and what does it mean regarding my string?!

Here's a screenshot, with the icon on the top string field -

[image: Better resolution with context]

The classes I've used to recreate this is:

```
namespace TEST_ENVIRONMENTS
{
    class locals_window_icon_test
    {
        protected string A = "";
        private string B;
    }

    class derived : locals_window_icon_test
    {
        public string C = "";
        public string D;

        public void method()
        {
            A = "Hey";
            C = "Guy";
            D = "Gop";
        }
    }
}
```

And this is run from an instance by:

```
namespace TEST_ENVIRONMENTS
{
    class _PROGRAM
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            derived x = new derived();
            x.method();
        }
    }
}
```

I just put a debug stop marker at the end of `method` and look at the variables in the Locals window.

Comment: I can't zoom enough to tell what I'm looking at. What are the 5 strings? Are they returned from functions, globals... - I suspect there's some other info in the column with their names

Comment: Yeah that's the problem I have - I can't magnify this window, that's just how they are - string values are e.g. top three "XX-10-02", "1" and "1184930019111" - Their "Type" is just "string" - they're all returned via a "ref `x`" where `x` is the variable name... I just don't know what the difference is, I thought it'd be easier to ask than to figure it out stepping through code.

Comment: The only inkling I have to go off is that the "rosette" string is inherited. But I have some inherited properties (rather than fields) which don't have any odd symbol attached?! Will do a small test now..

Comment: Of interest, C#?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have stated that in my question - I've just swapped a "public" for a "protected" and it came up with the rosette. So it seems to be linked to inherited, protected.

Comment: @jamheadart I recommend you take a better screenshot using some utility such as Greenshot.  Expand it so we can see it better.  It would also help to see a more complete screenshot (e.g. some context).

Comment: @jamheadart `I'm sure this is going to be a duplicate question but I'm obviously asking it wrong!` If I may, i would like to disagree with you here.  Searching for icons is simply difficult, and it isn't surprising you'd have to ask by using a screenshot.  In my opinion, this line in your question is unwarranted, and I doubt your question will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I removed the line, and added a PNG screenshot. I have found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx which has different icons on and "protected" is apparently a star - but this doesn't really seem to match my icon, unless it's a combination of "protected" and some other...

Comment: @jamheadart I agree, it's possible that icon is a combination of two icons.  It's also possible the icon is from a VS extension, and that's why we can't find it in the documentation.  Can you provide a code sample that reproduces this icon?  If I can get the same icon, maybe we can figure out what it is.  Does the same icon appear int the Watch and Autos windows?

Comment: I added some code that I can recreate the icon with, I also checked `Autos` (same icon was visible) and `Watch` - which had no symbols at all

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186350.aspx) is a list of icons. Probably not comprehensive though...

Comment: .NET knows more access modifiers than C#. For example, `protected internal` means `protected` OR `internal`, but the runtime also knows `protected` AND `internal`. So perhaps it isn't even reproducible in C#. Therefore, is the object that you have in the debugger from a library or from your (C#) code?

Comment: I'm not sure... I just recreated this in VB and get the same icons and I'm pretty sure it's just protected, but my version has some alternate icon for protected as opposed to the * that the documentation says it should/would be,

Comment: In VS2017 I get the protected star on A and a padlock on B. Possibly some corruption in your install. If restarts (first VS, then entire machine) doesn't fix it, try a repair. Because there should definitely be an overlay icon on B too

Comment: It isn't scaled all that well, flubs a bit at the bottom.  But if you look from the corner of your eye with the sun in your back and a stiff breeze to keep you cool then you can see a key.  Because it is *protected*.

Comment: So it WAS protected... just a bit of an odd graphical representation of it... Fantastci! Thanks all!

Comment: @jamheadart - Like I said, the lack of the padlock (or other indicator) on `B` points to it probably being corruption rather than deliberate.

Comment: Actually Damien, I do apologise, the screenshot with B lacking the padlock was taking before I swapped B to a private field. I think rather than corruption it's some locality or version setting that's a bit of a naff picture but nontheless means protected. Thanks again!